# Time complexity of a method that checks a sublist in a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, time-complexity

I need to write a method `public int subList (CharList list)`
that gets a list and returns how many times this list exist.

For example:

my list is `a b c d a b g e`

parameter list it`a b` it will return **2**.

my list is `b b b b`

parameter list is `b b` it will return **3**.

**The method should be as efficient as possible.**

Currently my problem is I don't know what do they mean when they say as efficient as possible, If I loop through the list n times, and everytime I find the same character I loop on both list and go back to where I was it will be O(n^2)? is there a better way to make is O(n) or below?

Comment: Below `O(n)`, that sounds like a challenge; an `O(1)` method that loops over a list... Complexity will always be `O(n)` in the best case here.

Comment: @Boris the Spider: Creepy crawly, creepy crawly, creepy crawly. Creepy creepy, crawley crawley. Creepy creepy, crawley crawley.

Comment: Do you need this because of an assignment or not? Because if not, you can just use repeated invocations of `Collections.indexOfSublist()`

Answer (score 2):

This is in effective searching string in a string, which is O(n) complexity

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm

and as you find first occurrence you can just keep looking for next occurrence in remaining list so it's still O(n) to find all occurrence

Comment: So in my example of b b b b (search for bb). even though when I find the second occurance and I keep looking at the same index, it's still O(n)?

Comment: after reading the article I must say it was a very good read, now my challenge is to code it ;p

Comment: after finding bb in bbbb then you get rid of the character include and before the index of match, which left bbb here, then you search with in that. of course you can get rid of more depend on your matching pattern, bb in bbbb is quite extreme example here, but it's actually linear overhead add up to make it complicated, in theory still O(n)

Answer (score 1):

Why `O(n^2)`? It is `O(n)` because the you need to iterate only once through the `list`.

Comment: Not quite.  It is O(NM) where N is list length and M is the sublist length.

Answer (score 1):

Lets do this with a char[] to simplify the explanation.

The simple approach is as follows:

```
public int countSublists (char[] list, char[] sublist)
    int count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= sublist.length; j++) {
            if (j = sublist.length) {
               count++;
            } else if (i + j > list.length || list[i + j] != sublist[j]) {
               break;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

This has **worst-case** complexity of `O(N*M)` where `N` is the length of `list` and `M` is the length of `sublist`.  And best-case complexity of `O(N)` ... when there are no instances of the first character of `sublist` in `list`.

There are various other algorithms that give better performance ... down to (I think) `O(N/M)` best-case.  The general idea is that you use the value of the character at list[i + j] when there is a mismatch to allow you to skip some characters.

You can find details of various advanced search algorithms are linked from the Wikipedia page on [String Searching algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm) ... which also includes a summary of the respective algorithm complexity.

But the thing to note is that the advanced search algorithms all involve some precompution steps, whose complexity is some function of `M`.  If `N` is small enough, the cost of the precomputation may outweigh the saving at search time.  (On the other hand, if you are repeatedly counting the same sublist in different lists, and you can reuse the precomputed tables, then you can amortize the precomputation cost ...)